# get_posts() SQL Injection

Tags: wpdb, security, get-posts

I'm working on a custom search page and I usually use wpdb->prepare when crafting custom queries. But this time I went with get_posts to create the below query. But I'm wondering if I have to worry about SQL Injection with it. Should I? Or does get_posts() have that security built in?

If not, how do I clean the incoming variables?

```
$SEARCH_QUERY = @$_GET['s2'];

$args2 = array(
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    's'                => $SEARCH_QUERY
);

$arrSearchResults = get_posts($args2);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrSearchResults);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I'd advise using `WP_Query` instead. `get_posts` won't fire post loop lifecycle events, and by default it does not use caches to avoid performance hits. As for a custom search page, you don't need to do this. The standard search page with a standard loop works just fine if you append query variables to the URL, e.g. `mysite.com/?s=test&post_type=test` will search all posts of type `test` for the string `test`, likewise if I had a hidden input in my search form named `post_type`

Comment: Also, you used the `@` operator, do not use that operator. It does not fix or swallow errors, it just hides the message from the error log, the error stll happens. Use `if ( ! empty( $_GET['s2'] ) {` and check if it exists instead of blindly accessing it

Comment: So you're saying that `get_posts` does not properly sanitize variables and provides no protection against SQL Injection?

Comment: I said nothing about SQL injections and `get_posts` parameters, these are the comments not the answers. ***`@` is extreme bad practice***. Avoid the PHP warning by checking if the array actually has a `h2` parameter, don't just silence it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If not, how do I clean the incoming variables?

In most cases you don't, `get_posts` calls `WP_Query` internally, and `WP_Query` performs some sanitization, namely via `wpdb->prepare`.

---

However, for what you're trying to do, this is the wrong approach. Just use a standard `search.php` template with a standard post loop, and use `input` fields that have the same names as the parameters for `WP_Query`. WP will automatically filter as a result of them being added to the URL. There is no need for a custom page template with a custom query and custom URL parameters. It's just unnecessary complexity, and double the database queries ( don't forget the broken pagination, dealing with 404's, etc )